# При запросе к БД, получаю какую-то ерунду вместо контента

Tags: java, база-данных, java-ee, jpa, ejb

Пытаюсь сделать элементарное приложение Jakarta EE9

Есть сущность, могу записать в БД данные, но когда пытаюсь эти данные получить приходит ерунда вида entity.DevNotes@2e48c0b1 - что это такое?
в таблице данные:

1 |1    |Porsche |911

В попытке вытянуть эти данные в Servlet пишу

```
...
  @EJB
    TestService testService;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(testService.findWithName("Porsche"));
    }
...
```

В контролере

```
...

    public List findWithName(String name) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return em.createQuery("select  c from DevNotes c where c.name like :custName")
                .setParameter("custName", name)
                .getResultList();
    }
...
```

Ошибок не выдает ни IDE, ни сервер, все компилируется красиво.
В консоль прилетает ответ:

entity.DevNotes@2e48c0b1

Что это?

Где мой Porsche 911?

Я понимаю, что entity - это имя пакета, а DevNotes - мой Entity-класс, но @2e48c0b1 ?

Comment: у DevNotes метод toString переопределен?

Comment: Нет. Спасибо вам добрые люди! Добавил метод и получил свой Porsche!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в `DevNotes` нет определенного метода `toString`, поэтому используется реализация из класса `Object`, а он такое выводит.

Переопределите `toString` в своем классе.